# Webpack hot loader throws "[HMS] Hot Module Replacement is disabled."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm trying to build a small react tool using webpack. The following is my configuration.

```
var path = require('path'),
    node_modules_dir = path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules');

var deps = [
  'react/dist/react.min.js',
  'react/dist/react.js'
];

var config = {
  entry: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, "app/v3.jsx"),
    './node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "transpiled.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/ }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Here is my command line argument:

```
$ webpack-dev-server --hot --inline --progress --colors
```

I still see a message in the browser console saying "[HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled."

Needs help.

The following is the link to github issue related to this one. It still doesnt solve my problem.

[Github link to this issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1151)

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your entry config. Everything else looks alright.

```
entry: [
'webpack-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080',
'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
 path.resolve(__dirname, "app/v3.jsx")
]
```